# Redirect page and send var value using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I redirect to page star.php using

```
window.location.href = 'start.php';
```

Before I redirect I just want to send(post) 
`var userid` to start.php

how could I do?

Answer (score 1):

you can not post like this. Instead pass it through url like:

```
window.location.href = 'start.php?userid='+userid;
```

and you will get the value as `$_GET['userid']` in start.php

Comment: happy diwali and thanks a lot. It will be receive using 
`<?php var val=$_POST['userid']>` correct?

Comment: No, it will be `$_GET['userid']`.